# Criar div com append e apagar para exibir outra usando Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

Preciso exibir mensagens de validação de erros num formulário.
Essas mensagens vêm de um json quando submeto o form.
Só que um campo pode ter 2 ou mais msgs, por exemplo:
Um cpf pode ter mensagens de erro como: Campo inválido ou Campo vazio.

Consegui exibir a mensagem de erro, só que quando clico novamente ele duplica a mensagem ao invés de substituir por uma nova.
Como faço pra apagar a mensagem atual e substituir pela nova?

Meu código é esse:

```
$.each(errorVal, function(i, item){
    console.log("messsagem: " + item.defaultMessage)
    if(item.field === "cpf") {
        $('#cpf-row').append('<small class="alert-error" data-js="alert-error" id="alert-error"> Name: ' + item.defaultMessage + '</small>');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para apagar seu elemento utilize a função `remove()` do JQuery:

```
$('#alert-error').remove();

$.each(errorVal, function(i, item){
    console.log("messsagem: " + item.defaultMessage)

    if(item.field === "cpf") {
        $('#cpf-row').append('<small class="alert-error" data-js="alert-error" id="alert-error"> Name: ' + item.defaultMessage + '</small>');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Deu certo dessa maneira quando coloco 1 campo só, mas o form tem vários campos, aí precisei fazer o seguinte

'  $.each(errorVal, function(i, item){
                var msgError = '<small class="alert-error" data-js="alert-error"> ' + item.defaultMessage + '</small>';

               $('#alert-error').remove();
                $('#'+item.field +'-row').append(msgError);

              }) ' 

Dessa forma, ele fica alternando, apaga todos e só mostra 1

Comment: Alterei a resposta, por favor tente novamente.

Comment: Deu certo :) obrigada!!!

Comment: Por nada!!!!!!!